# Invalid Cast error while adding items to a List<double>

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, casting, double

I have one problem. I'm writing an application in c# using Visual Studio. In application i have dataTable with columns products, price, and quantity. For each column i tried to save all rows from data table in list. For example:

```
List<string> products = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    products.Add(dt.Rows[i]["products"].ToString());               
}
```

This code works fine. Problem is when I try to save data from column price into double list. I tried many ways and none of them are correct. What i tried to do is. 
For example

```
List<double> prices = new List<double>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    prices.Add((double)dt.Rows[i]["price"]);
}
```

I'm always getting an error saying `Specified cast is not valid`. I also tried with `double parse` where it says: `input string was not in correct format`.
All I want to do is to store data from data table into double list.

Comment: What is the value of `dt.Rows[i]["price"]` exactly when you debug your code?

Comment: Print out the items that you are trying to convert to double and check that there are no nulls, empty strings, spaces or badly formatted numeric strings.

Comment: What type is price in your Database?

Comment: `Parse` was a good idea! Since "input string was not in a correct format", did you check out what the input string actually was? Maybe periods `.` and/or commas `,` were used in another way than your .NET culture expects? Maybe there were some characters, like a currency designator like `$` or `USD` or something, present.

Comment: Price is present as for example 9,8 with comma. Could that be a problem. Should be present with dot?

Comment: try `prices.Add(double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString(),NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`

Comment: Seems quite right but there's an error
Error. NumberStyles and CultureInfo does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I fixed that but still i get the same error. Input string is not in correct format

Comment: InvariantCulture wants a dot, not a comma and your numbers have commas so you'll get that error. Try CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Comment: i know that. I tried, no success. I think that the problem is not anymore trying to put data in list but trying to change that comma into dot in database

Comment: Problem is fixed if i create list<string> instead list<double>. I can store values in it and display them. That works perfectly fine but when and if i tired to sum my price it appears a problem because i can't sum strings. That is way i tried to add my values to list<double>

Comment: What country and language does the string `9,8` with comma belong to? .NET supports many languages and countries. I take it that the `9,8` is supposed to mean "nine wholes and eight tenths", which is usually called "nine point eight" in English?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

then

```
 prices.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match(dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString().Trim(), 
                   @"\d+").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Getting error Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @user3201743 Please show what data is there in ' dt.Rows[i]["price"] '

Comment: In database i have price data set as data type money. In datatable which are readed from database are present as for example 9,8 with ,.

Comment: Hmm.. i copied your code but i get an error that Error  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Trim' and no extension method 'Trim' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: Sorry , you have to add .ToString() before trim , as shown in the answere

Comment: Still :) Input string was not in a correct format. Looks like i'll have to change datatype in my database am i?

Comment: prices.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString().Trim().Replace(",","."),
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: Good idea, but still error. Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Problem is fixed if i create list<string> instead list<double>. I can store values in it and display them. That works perfectly fine but when and if i tired to sum my price it appears a problem because i can't sum strings. That is way i tried to add my values

Comment: Ok try this one...Editted the answere...prices.Add(Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match(dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString().Trim(), @"\d+").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Answer (score 0):

try with `Trim`, you may have space before or after

```
prices.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString().Trim(),
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

using linq you can do this as below ( add `using System.Linq;`)

```
List<double> doubles = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(r => r.Field<double>(1)) // assume price column index is 1
                            .ToList();
```

you can use [`Double.Parse Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you have elements such as white space, thousands separators, and currency symbols in your price

if you have comma in your price, try like below

```
prices.Add(double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString(),NumberStyles.AllowThousa‌​nds, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Do you really want to "cast" a string `s` to `double` with `(double)s` syntax? Edit: If `Trim()` were actually in scope, since its return type is `string`, it would be a compile-time error to cast to `double`. However `Trim()` is hardly valid since the compile-time type is likely `object`(?).

Comment: with linq i still get same error.
The last one with numberStyles seems quite right but when i copy your code i get error: The name 'NumberStyles', 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current contex

Comment: @user3201743 add using System.Globalization;

Comment: @Rok Given info from your comment to the question (not to this answer), do you want to parse `"9,8"` (nine comma eight) as `98` (ninety-eight)? Because if you allow thousand separators and use the `InvariantCulture`, the comma will more or less be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Convert.ToDouble` function:

```
prices.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["price"]));
```

If you still get an error message you possibly got a culture problem.
When your prices are using the decimal seperator `","` instead of `"."` or you have some seperator for thousends (for example `"1,523.25"`) you may have to also define the Culture as a second parameter to `Convert.ToDouble`